# Using CGFLOAT_MAX to hide UITableViewCell separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to hide the separator for a specific `UITableViewCell` and am using `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, CGFLOAT_MAX, 0.0, 0.0);`.  This causes very weird problems on older devices and works perfectly on newer devices.  On an iPhone 5 for example, it will cause the cell to flicker and be blurry.  Changing `CGFLOAT_MAX` to a fixed number like `5000.0` makes all of the issues disappear.  Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Any idea why this is happening or thoughts?  Sorry if you couldn't infer the question...

Comment: Well the iPhone 5 is 32-bit and newer devices aren't so if I had to guess I would assume there is some issue with using CGFLOAT_MAX as a frame value on 32-bit devices.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but wondered if anyone knew concretely.

Comment: Do both devices have the same iOS version?

Comment: Just to be more sane, I'd try something like `UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGRectGetWidth(tableView), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);` instead of maxFloat.

Comment: @moby I tried what you recommended, but changing the orientation from portrait to landscape causes a problem  I can see the separator in landscape.

Comment: @jherg try using the UIScreen height then as left inset so that it handles both max case in portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 0):

That approach sounds unwise. You’re probably best off just disabling the table’s default separators and having your cells (minus the one you want it hidden for) draw their own, either in their `-drawRect:` or by adding a thin view at the top or bottom of each cell.

There’s also the solution described [here](http://johnszumski.com/blog/hiding-table-separators-on-a-cell-by-cell-basis)—setting the horizontal insets to half the width of the cell, so the separator ends up being 0pt in width—but given the history of changes listed in that article you can probably expect that to end up breaking as well.

Answer (score -1):

Running on iOS 9.1, I am seeing a similar issue on iPad.

In my case the screen flickers black whenever it's launched (my cell is on the initial screen); or whenever I use Split View on iPad Air 2; resizing my app causes flickering when my app is rendered.

I have bug reported this to Apple as I think we should be able to use `CGFLOAT_MAX` instead of a magical high number to achieve the same effect. In fact I've even suggested that perhaps we should have an API to hide the separator; I'm sure many before myself have asked for this though.

rdar://23768136 (I will update here whenever I get any news on it). In the mean time, just use a silly big number that's for sure going to get the separator hidden - something like 5000.